# Android: Unable to start admin status granting activity from service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, device-admin

I am using the following code to start the activity that asks the user to grant an application, device admin status.

```
        mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        try {
            mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(this, WatchDogAdmin.class);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }  

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
//        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ShuntActivity.class);
        intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent2.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminSample);
        intent2.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Device admin rights are required for this application to work correctly.");
//        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ENABLE);
        startActivity(intent2);
```

What am i doing wrong ? There is no error, the activity simply does not launch.

Comment: Try getting rid of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Comment: Doing results in the application crashing. What is the reason for you to suggest that ?

Comment: Otherwise, your code seemed to line up with some stuff that I have done with `DevicePolicyManager`, which is why I asked.

Comment: Yeah, the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is not required when launching from an activity. It IS however required when starting from another service.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line,

```
intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `WatchDogAdmin` is the receiver and try `startActivityForResult(intent2, 1);`